# Adding auto layout constraints in a tableview cell.

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to add a `UIImageView` to a cell and programmatically add auto layout constraints. However, it is giving me this following error: `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint... When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.` I looked at these following posts: [Swift, Constraint, The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465671/swift-constraint-the-view-hierarchy-is-not-prepared-for-the-constraint), [Why is my layout constraint returning an error in this case? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654412/why-is-my-layout-constraint-returning-an-error-in-this-case-swift), and [Swift, Constraint, The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465671/swift-constraint-the-view-hierarchy-is-not-prepared-for-the-constraint). One thing that I could not add to my code that these posts were suggesting me to add is `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. When I try to add this function to my `imageView`, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
    func cellTwo(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CathyTaskLogTwoTableViewCell

        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "defaultPicture"))
        imageView.frame.size.width = 100
        imageView.frame.size.height = 31
                let horizonalContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute:
            .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: cell,
            attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 20)
        imageView.addConstraint(horizonalContraints)

        cell.addSubview(imageView)

        return cell

    }
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help :)

Comment: Is `cellTwo` a storyboard identifier for a cell prototype? Or did you register a class for that identifier? Or did you register a NIB with that identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The sequence is:

   - instantiate the subview (e.g. the image view);
   - set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`;
   - call `addSubview` to add it to the view hierarchy; and
   - add the constraints.
2. Do not set the `frame` at all if you're using constraints. Everything should be defined by constraints.
3. It is probably not prudent to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and then add a subview. What if the cell is being reused? You'll be adding the same subview multiple times. The programmatic adding of subview is probably best put in the cell subclass implementation of `awakeFromNib`, if from storyboard or NIB, or `init(style;, reuseIdentifier)` if building it programmatically. Or, easiest, don't programmatically create cells at all and use storyboard or NIB.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding constraints to any view programmatically you should add it as subview and turn translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false and then add your required constraints. Like

```
 cell.addSubview(imageView)
 imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

 //now add your required constraints
```

Comment: I was able to add `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` as you have suggested. However, it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Have you moved your code of adding imageView as subview up, i.e before adding constraints as i suggested in answer

Comment: `cell.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        imageView.addConstraint(horizonalContraints)` 
is what I have so far. And yet,  I am still getting an error.

Comment: try cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView) instead of cell.addSubview(imageView)